# How to count summary of integer values of each row from Multidimensional table in C#?

Tags: c#

I have table 4 x 4 and wanna get summary of 3 integer values in last columns

```
public class Table
{
        static void Main()
        {
            int row, column;
            int sumrow = 0;
            int sumcolumn = 0;

            int[,] numbers = new int[4, 4];

            for (row = 0; row < 3;row++)
            {
                for (column = 0; column < 3 ; column++)
                {

                    Console.Write("Give number to place [" + row + "," + column + "]: ");
                    numbers[row, column] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }


            for (row = 0; row < 2; row++) // how to count it?
            {
                for (column = 0; column < 3; column++)
                {
                    sumrow = numbers[ row ,column] + sumrow;
                    numbers[0, 3] = sumrow;   
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: The question is "how to count summary of integer values", but I don't understand what the question means. Remus, can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you request user input, you have a two-dimensional array with all zeroes in the last row and column, for instance:

```
 1  2  3  0
 4  5  6  0
 7  8  9  0
 0  0  0  0
```

And you want the last rows and columns to be populated with the sum of the respective row or column:

```
 1  2  3  6
 4  5  6 15
 7  8  9 24
12 15 18 45
```

Each non-summary entry in the array contributes to three totals: the row total, the column total, and the grand total (sum of all elements), like so:

```
 0  0  0  0
 0  X  0  X
 0  0  Y  Y
 0  X  Y  X+Y
```

As one approach, you can enumerate through each data (non-summary) element, and update the three respective summary elements accordingly:

```
int rowCount = numbers.GetLength(0) - 1; // # rows, exc. total
int columnCount = numbers.GetLength(1) - 1; // # cols, exc. total
for (row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    for (column = 0; column < columnCount; column++)
    {
        int cell = numbers[row, column];
        checked // throw on arithmetic overflow
        {
             numbers[row, columnCount] += cell;
             numbers[rowCount, column] += cell;
             numbers[rowCount, columnCount] += cell;   
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this approach assumes the last row and column are initially all zeroes, which holds in your example.  It does not require the original array be square.

Comment: Thanks man, I only got the summary of all values, coudnt get how to count only summary of each row or column....

Answer (score 0):

You could sum the columns of a 2-d array as follows:

```
IEnumerable<int> columnSums = Enumerable
    .Range(0, numbers.GetLength(0))
    .Select(col => Enumerable
                     .Range(0, numbers.GetLength(1))
                     .Sum(row => numbers[col, row]))
```

Untested and possibly with columns and rows the wrong way round...

Comment: hmmm... i tried but still im getting 0 in last columns